# IdentityServer4 Role Based Authorization for ASP.NET Core Identity = Access Denied

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver4, access-token, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an ASP.NET Core client application that uses an IdentityServer4 as login server. The client can login decorating the controller with the attribute `[Authorize]` but if I use the attribute with roles `[Authorize(Roles = "test")]` I get an **Access-Denied**

However, when I parse the JWT I can see that the user has assigned the correct role.

```
{
  "nbf": xxx,
  "exp": xxx,
  "iss": "xxx",
  "aud": [
    "xxx",
    "xxx"
  ],
  "client_id": "xxx",
  "sub": "xxx",
  "auth_time": xxx,
  "idp": "xxx",
  "email": "xxx",
  "role": "test", <-------------------------------
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "xxx",
    "xxx"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "xxx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe show an example User with the Claims, when you are using QuickStart you prolly have the Config. Did you define any Policies? Maybe check out PolicyServer.Local, it is very leightweight but also an easy and effective way to implement roles.

Comment: @SergSam policies is an advanced step. First the OP has to ensure his Identity in web app carries roles inside.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Even so the user role is present in the access-token it is not recognized as role, since it is part of the user-claims. 
For example `User.IsInRole("test")` returns false.

I solved the issue by creating a policy to use the `RequireClaim` and then set the `Authorize` attribute to use the policy, such as `[Authorize(Policy = "RequireUserOnly")]`

Comment: this is not the correct solution. to allow the system behaving as designed, you have to include your roles into identity token either by configuring 'IdentityResourses' on IdSrv side or manually constructing your internal client's identity ticket in 'OpenIdConnectEvents.OnTokenValidated' delegate

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you are attaching the correct jwt. The one you presented looks good, but probably you attached to request the id_token which has different payload.

Comment: Well, once the client login it should automatically the proper jwt.

Comment: oidc introduces two tokens at a time: id_token contains user session and should not be sent outside, and access token, or just token is the berier one aimed to be attached to api calls

Comment: I know about the jwt for the API but how the client app can use the token with role?

Comment: something like: `httpClient.SendAsync(
                        new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, yourApiEndpoint)
            {
              Headers = 
              {
                    Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken)
              }
            });`

Comment: The ASP.NET client connected to the IdentityServer to be authenticate. I only have an IdentityServer and an ASP.NET We UI, I do not have any API.

Comment: so where you set your role based restrictions? I guess that was api!

Comment: Nope, it is an ASP.NET Web app

Comment: so in this case you, probably have the opposite situation - your roles are in acces token only, when your Web app uses id_token internally, in such case you have to add roles claim to your `IdentityResourses`, not `ApiResources`

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Compare your IdentityResourses and ApiResources definitions , they must both contain roles - and the best example is official documentation. See the documentation on how to configure http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html